# NSIndexPath: a useful lldb summary string

Tags: xcode, string, lldb, summary, nsindexpath

While debugging with lldb in Xcode I would like to see in a debugger window a simple summary string for NSIndexPath objects. Something like:

> indexPath = (NSIndexPath *) { section=2 : row=0 }

would be much more helpful then what is displayed by lldb by default:

> indexPath = (NSIndexPath *) [NSIndexPath * @ scalar section]

I did try many summary string formatters written to my .lldbinit file, with these among them:

> type summary add NSIndexPath --summary-string '${var.section}'
>
> type summary add NSIndexPath --summary-string '${[var section]}'
>
> type summary add NSIndexPath --summary-string '[${var section}]'
>
> type summary add NSIndexPath --summary-string '[${var} section]'

The result for first three is:

> indexPath NSIndexPath *   error: summary string parsing error 0x08e309a0

and for the last one is:

> indexPath NSIndexPath *   [NSIndexPath * @ scalar section]    0x08a45b80

which is not much more helpful neither.

Do you know how to force lldb to display some more useful summary string for NSIndexPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(lldb) type summary add NSIndexPath -s "${var%@}"

This will essentially show you the same output that

(lldb) po myIndexPath

would - at the cost of running an expression every time you're looking at an index path, which may or may not be what you want

Comment: Yes, this produces the following output: `indexPath NSIndexPath * <NSIndexPath: 0x8c9c970> {length = 2, path = 1 - 1} 0x08c9c970`. This is not exactly I was dreaming of, but is far more communicative then the default output, and saves me this annoying clicking on uncollapse triangle just to see section and row/item. Thank you :)